# ON_NOTIFY not working in my dialog when I have ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT defined by the control

Tags: c++, mfc

In my CTreeCtrl derived class, I am acting on TVN_ITEMEXPANDED:

```
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_ITEMEXPANDED, &OnTVNItemExpanded)
```

In the control's parent dialog, I also want to act upon the same notification, TVN_ITEMEXPANDED,

```
ON_NOTIFY(TVN_ITEMEXPANDED, IDC_ELEMENT_TREE, &OnTVNItemExpanded)
```

However, only the control class's OnTVNItemExpanded method is getting called, never my dialog's.  I am using both breakpoints and seeing the desired behavior (or lack of desired behavior) in both methods to verify that only the control class's method is being called, not my dialog's method.

BUT, if I comment out the ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT from my CTreeCtrl-derived `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`, then my dialog's method gets called!?!

Why can't the notification go *both* to my control and to my dialog?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT` overrides `ON_NOTIFY`, but you can use `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX` instead which lets your callback decide if the message should go through to the parent or not.

See [Message Reflection for Windows Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd.aspx) for a more detailed explanation:

> If, in your parent window class, you supply a handler for a specific
>   **WM_NOTIFY** message or a range of **WM_NOTIFY** messages, your handler will
>   be called only if the child control sending those messages does not
>   have a reflected message handler through **ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT()**. If you
>   use **ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX()** in your message map, your message handler
>   may or may not allow the parent window to handle the message. If the
>   handler returns **FALSE**, the message will be handled by the parent as
>   well, while a call that returns **TRUE** does not allow the parent to
>   handle it. Note that the reflected message is handled before the
>   notification message.